# Docker containers cannot work with Nvidia nsight systems

Tags: docker, nsight

I am recently learning to use cuda programming and want to use nvidia's tool Nvidia nsight systems to visualize the programs I have written. I have done profile analysis on my personal laptop remotely to the server. Now I have installed cuda on my own laptop with nsight systems software. When I remotely go to the server, he can work. And will display the running timeline. But my program is written in the docker container, when I use nsight systems to link docker, it will fail. Why is this? I mapped my docker to 5222 on the host port. And ensure that the docker container can be directly connected through ssh.
The operating system of the notebook is ubuntu16.04
The operating system of the server is ubuntu16.04
The docker image I use is: nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorrt:20.03-py3
it show that: tool library installation failed!
[image: the nsight result picture]

Comment: Did you click on the `More info...` link next to the error message? What does that tell you?

Comment: thank u, i solve the problem by nvidia doc,if we want to use nvidia nsight remote to docker, we should Open ports 22 and 45555 by mapping the 22 port of the container to any port of the host, and mapping any port of the container to 45555 of the host.

Answer (score 1):

OK, i solve the problem by nvidia doc,if we want to use nvidia nsight remote to docker, we should Open ports 22 and 45555 by mapping the 22 port of the container to any port of the host, and mapping any port of the container to 45555 of the host.

Comment: what do you mean "mapping any port of the container to 45555 of the host"? Is SSH server installed and started in the docker container?